# mysql if() with max()

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I have a table named `attproduct`:

there are three columns `id, attribute, values`.

I have `color` and `brand` for each `id` in `attribute` column and corresponding values in `value` column

```
SELECT id, MAX( IF( attribute =  'brand', value, NULL ) ) AS Brand,
       MAX( IF( attribute =  'color', value, NULL ) ) AS color
FROM fy.attproduct
GROUP BY id
```

When I run this query i get output as desired in `id, brand, color` as columns.

I need to know what is role of max in my query, when i remove max, i get null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MAX()` is combining the values associated with each id.

```
SELECT id, IF( attribute =  'brand', value, NULL ) AS Brand, IF( attribute =  'color', value, NULL ) AS color
FROM fy.attproduct
```

without the `GROUP BY` should return rows like

```
ID  Brand      color
1   'mybrand'  NULL
1   NULL       'mycolor'
```

When `MAX()` is not used, only one of the rows will be chosen, so at least one column will be `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

`group by id` will roll all the rows in attproduct that are associated with a given id into one result row. If you don't specify an aggregator like min or max, a random value from the source rows will be selected for the result (likely the first found).