# why `if(id=max(id), id, id+1)` doesn't work as expected in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

in the follow table `People`:

```
id name
 1 James
 2 Yun
 3 Ethan
```

if I want to find the max id I can run this query

```
select max(id) id from People;
```

the result is

```
id
 3
```

if I want to increase id by 1 for all rows except the last one, I tried this:

```
select if(id=max(id), id, id+1) id, name from People
```

surprisingly, I got

[image]

why `max()` doesn't work as previous case? and why there is only one row (looks like only the 1st row) returned?
I think I know how to fix this, as below:

```
select if(id=lastID, id, id+1) id,, name from People,
(select max(id) lastID from People) People_max
order by id;
```

then I got what I expected:

[image]

But I think I still don't know why the previous one doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: should you define a variable for it? `SET @id = max(id)`

Comment: might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354963/mysql-if-with-max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a subquery to obtain the max value:

```
SELECT
    IF(id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM People), id, id+1) id,
    name
FROM People
ORDER BY id;
```

When you were referring to `MAX(id)` in your original single-level query, you were telling MySQL to execute the query in table level aggregation mode.  This means it will return just a single record representing an aggregate of the entire table.  By switching to a subquery, it behaves the way you want.  By the way, if you are using MySQL 8+, then we can use analytic functions here to make the query a bit less verbose:

```
SELECT
    IF(id = MAX(id) OVER (), id, id+1) id,
    name
FROM People
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: the analytical function `over()`, is that related to `row_number` function? does that mean MySQL8+ support that? I'm actually use MariaDB since I like the HeidySQL that comes with it. Is there something like that if I download MySQL8+? is that easy to install (I find some MariaDB version is difficult to install)?

Comment: MariaDB might support analytic functions as well, if it be a more recent version.